Video autoplay on Instagram InApp Browser dont work - but only on the first siteloading
have a classic embedded video throuh the html video tag. This works great untill if you open the site through the instagram app for the first time, the autoplay dont work. Strange behaviour, if you load an other site and retours everything works fine. If you open the site in the mobile browser it works fine too. It's is only on the first opening that the autoplay dont't work. And this behavior has only been going on for a few days, before it work well.
HTML
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" playsinline="" preload="auto" class="VideoResponsive_video__veJBa"><source src="https://videos.ctfassets.net/e4lmb8z9jwqd/4Yu4UYeBHErRTnHVUmk2jg/8022c18b3d9a4c432fcc8e77d9a7e58d/Agobay_coming_soon_16x9.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

Thanks for help on how to solve this
